# is there a way to change two texts in list element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

my problem is that when i use two .textContent method on the same list element to change text it doesn't work , but when i comment the if else block everything go well. all what i want is to display both of them after changing textcontent ,but when i do that the spans content disappear which has temperatures.

```js
// those are just selectors i think theres nothing wrong with them
const span1 = document.querySelector('#span1');
const span2 = document.querySelector('#span2');
const span3 = document.querySelector('#span3');
const span4 = document.querySelector('#span4');
const span5 = document.querySelector('#span5');

const list1 = document.querySelector('#l1')
const list2 = document.querySelector('#l2');
const list3 = document.querySelector('#l3');
const list4 = document.querySelector('#l4');
const list5 = document.querySelector('#l5');
// those are just selectors i think theres nothing wrong with them


if ((currentHour + 3) >= 10) {
  list1.textContent = "Now";
  list2.textContent = `${currentHour + 3}:00`;
  list3.textContent = (currentHour + 6) + ':00';
  list4.textContent = (currentHour + 9) + ':00';
  list5.textContent = (currentHour + 12) + ':00';
} else {
  list1.textContent = "Now";
  list2.textContent = '0' + (currentHour + 3) + ':00';
  list3.textContent = '0' + (currentHour + 6) + ':00';
  list4.textContent = '0' + (currentHour + 9) + ':00';
  list5.textContent = '0' + (currentHour + 12) + ':00';
}

span1.textContent = data.currentTemp + '°C';
span2.textContent = data.temp3 + '°C';
span3.textContent = data.temp6 + '°C';
span4.textContent = data.temp9 + '°C';
span5.textContent = data.temp12 + '°C';
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="l1">Now<span id="span1"> </span></li>
  <li id="l2">09:00<span id="span2"> </span></li>
  <li id="l3">12:00<span id="span3"> </span></li>
  <li id="l4">15:00<span id="span4"> </span></li>
  <li id="l5">18:00 <span id="span5"> </span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please use the _"Tidy"_ button before you insert your snippet

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -> _'"It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Use a brief but descriptive summary of your problem as the title of your question.'_

Comment: Changing the textContent of the <li> elements removes the <span>s. Just use two spans instead (or a table).

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent: _“Setting textContent on a node removes all of the node's children and replaces them with a single text node with the given string value.”_ - so you can not use this to replace _just_ the text `Now` in the first LI, and expect the `span` element to survive. Either wrap that first text into a span as well (so that you can access _both_ of those texts individually), or access the actual text _node_ contained in the LI, and change the value of that.

Comment: Here's code that creates the list content from scratch: https://jsfiddle.net/kdw098L2/

Comment: @CBroe thank you so much it worked ,and sorry that i couldn't declare my problem more

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this where temperature and time has a span each.

Your way of displaying time needed to be corrected too.
There will still be a problem if your currentTime is >= 13 and time5 becomes 25:00.

```js
let currentHour = 6;

let data = {
  "currentTemp": 5,
  "temp3": 6,
  "temp6": 3,
  "temp9": 8,
  "temp12": 5,
}

// those are just selectors i think theres nothing wrong with them
const time1 = document.querySelector('#time1');
const time2 = document.querySelector('#time2');
const time3 = document.querySelector('#time3');
const time4 = document.querySelector('#time4');
const time5 = document.querySelector('#time5');

const temperature1 = document.querySelector('#temperature1')
const temperature2 = document.querySelector('#temperature2');
const temperature3 = document.querySelector('#temperature3');
const temperature4 = document.querySelector('#temperature4');
const temperature5 = document.querySelector('#temperature5');
// those are just selectors i think theres nothing wrong with them



time1.textContent = "Now";

if ((currentHour + 3) >= 10) {
  time2.textContent = (currentHour + 3) + ':00';
} else {
  time2.textContent = '0' + (currentHour + 3) + ':00';
}
if ((currentHour + 6) >= 10) {
  time3.textContent = (currentHour + 6) + ':00';
} else {
  time3.textContent = '0' + (currentHour + 6) + ':00';
}
if ((currentHour + 9) >= 10) {
  time4.textContent = (currentHour + 9) + ':00';
} else {
  time4.textContent = '0' + (currentHour + 9) + ':00';
}
if ((currentHour + 12) >= 10) {
  time5.textContent = (currentHour + 12) + ':00';
} else {
  time5.textContent = '0' + (currentHour + 12) + ':00';
}

temperature1.textContent = data.currentTemp + '°C';
temperature2.textContent = data.temp3 + '°C';
temperature3.textContent = data.temp6 + '°C';
temperature4.textContent = data.temp9 + '°C';
temperature5.textContent = data.temp12 + '°C';
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span = id="time1">Now</span> <span id="temperature1"> </span></li>
  <li><span = id="time2">09:00</span> <span id="temperature2"> </span></li>
  <li><span = id="time3">12:00</span> <span id="temperature3"> </span></li>
  <li><span = id="time4">15:00</span> <span id="temperature4"> </span></li>
  <li><span = id="time5">18:00</span> <span id="temperature5"> </span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you guys i actually solved it  , i just used .innerHtml instead of textcontent so then i changed both the span element and list text in one move i think its bad to use it for security matter but its not a problem for a personal project to learn

Answer (score 0):

Because `textContent`s in the script have only values without adding span. For example

`list1.textContent = "Now";` makes `list1`'s content into

`"Now"`

even if `span1.textContent = data.currentTemp + '°C';`.

For this problem values can be added like `list1.textContent = "Now" + span1.textContent;`.

So in the script in each `list`'s value `span` value is appended like

`list1.appendChild(span1);`

which puts the `span` value like `10°C` into the `list` tag.

Then in the `list` tag (have `10°C` value) hours value like `11:00` is added over the degree value.

```js
// those are just selectors i think theres nothing wrong with them
const span1 = document.querySelector('#span1');
const span2 = document.querySelector('#span2');
const span3 = document.querySelector('#span3');
const span4 = document.querySelector('#span4');
const span5 = document.querySelector('#span5');

const list1 = document.querySelector('#l1')
const list2 = document.querySelector('#l2');
const list3 = document.querySelector('#l3');
const list4 = document.querySelector('#l4');
const list5 = document.querySelector('#l5');
// those are just selectors i think theres nothing wrong with them


let currentHour = 9;

let data = {
  temp3: 10,
  temp6: 11,
  temp9: 12,
  temp12: 13,
}

span1.textContent = data.temp3 +'°C';
span2.textContent = data.temp3 + '°C';
span3.textContent = data.temp6 + '°C';
span4.textContent = data.temp9 + '°C';
span5.textContent = data.temp12 + '°C';

list1.appendChild(span1);
list2.appendChild(span2);
list3.appendChild(span3);
list4.appendChild(span4);
list5.appendChild(span5);

if ((currentHour + 3) >= 10) {
  list1.textContent = "Now " + list1.textContent ;
  list2.textContent = `${currentHour + 3}:00 ` + list2.textContent;
  list3.textContent = (currentHour + 6) + ':00 ' + list3.textContent;
  list4.textContent = (currentHour + 9) + ':00 ' + list4.textContent;
  list5.textContent = (currentHour + 12) + ':00 ' + list5.textContent;
} else {
  list1.textContent = "Now " + list1.textContent;
  list2.textContent = '0' + (currentHour + 3) + ':00 ' + list2.textContent;
  list3.textContent = '0' + (currentHour + 6) + ':00 ' + list3.textContent;
  list4.textContent = '0' + (currentHour + 9) + ':00 ' + list4.textContent;
  list5.textContent = '0' + (currentHour + 12) + ':00 ' + list5.textContent;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li id="l1"><span id="span1"> </span></li>
  <li id="l2"><span id="span2"> </span></li>
  <li id="l3"><span id="span3"> </span></li>
  <li id="l4"><span id="span4"> </span></li>
  <li id="l5"> <span id="span5"> </span></li>
</ul>
```